# Multiplying two half-precision floats in procedural VHDL

Tags: floating-point, vhdl

I'm trying to implement a procedural half-float multiply function in VHDL. As things stand, I have this:

```vhdl
function "*" (l,r: half_float) return half_float is
    variable l_full_mantissa, r_full_mantissa: unsigned(l.mantissa'length downto 0);
    variable multiplied_mantissae: unsigned((l.mantissa'length + 1) * 2 - 1 downto 0);
    variable new_exponent: unsigned(fp16_exponent_len - 1 downto 0);
    begin

        if (l = fp16_zero or r = fp16_zero) then
            return fp16_zero;
        end if;
        report "L-Mantissa: " & to_string(l.mantissa);
        report "R-Mantissa: " & to_string(r.mantissa);
        report "L-Exponent: " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(l.exponent)));
        report "R-Exponent: " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(r.exponent)));
        new_exponent := unsigned(l.exponent) + (unsigned(r.exponent) - to_unsigned(fp16_exponent_bias, get_width_for_unsigned(fp16_exponent_bias))); -- Subtract the bias to prevent double counting
        report "N-Exponent: " & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(new_exponent)));

        -- Prepend the leading 1s
        l_full_mantissa := unsigned('1' & l.mantissa);
        r_full_mantissa := unsigned('1' & r.mantissa);

        report integer'image(to_integer(l_full_mantissa));
        report integer'image(to_integer(r_full_mantissa));

        -- Multiply the mantissae
        multiplied_mantissae := l_full_mantissa * r_full_mantissa;
        multiplied_mantissae := multiplied_mantissae sll 2; -- <-- not sure about this

        report integer'image(to_integer(multiplied_mantissae));
        report to_string(multiplied_mantissae);

        return (l.sign xor r.sign, std_logic_vector(new_exponent), std_logic_vector(multiplied_mantissae(multiplied_mantissae'high downto multiplied_mantissae'high - fp16_mantissa_len + 1)));
    end function;
```

And this seems to work for all of these test cases **except** for the last:

```vhdl
        report "Testing 5x2";
        assert to_float(five) * to_float(two) = to_float(ten);

        report "Testing 2x42";
        assert to_float(two) * to_float(forty_two) = to_float(eighty_four);

        report "Testing 2.5x4";
        assert to_float(two_point_five_slv) * to_float(four) = to_float(ten);

        report "Testing -4x2.5";
        assert to_float(minus_four) * to_float(two_point_five_slv) = to_float(minus_ten);

        report "Testing 0.25x0.25";
        assert to_float(one_quarter) * to_float(one_quarter) = to_float(one_sixteenth);

        report "Testing 0.45x4" severity note;
        assert to_float(point_four_five) * to_float(four) = to_float(one_point_eight);

        report "Testing 0.0005x640";
        assert to_float(point_o_o_o_five) * to_float(six_forty) = to_float(point_three_two);

        report "Testing -0.96x-0.96";
        assert to_float(minus_point_nine_six) * to_float(minus_point_nine_six) = to_float(point_nine_two_one_four);
```

For `-0.96x-0.96` I get `0.4214` rather than `0.9216`.

There's an `sll 2` in my function that I'm not entirely sure why it's needed. I'm also not sure what exactly makes my last case different from the others. Consequently, I expect that's where I'm missing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you multiply two binaries of the form `1.xxx... * 1.yyy...` the result can be anything between `1.000...` and `11.zzz`, so you need to decide how many leading digits you have to drop. (I don't know VHDL, so I can't help you with that)

Comment: Most importantly, `multiplied_mantissa` could be `1.11...111` which needs to be rounded up, so the number of shifts can only be decided after that (but if you already have a leading `10.zzz` or `11.zzz` you need to round differently)

Comment: I'm happy enough to implement it in vhdl once I know whatr needs to be done algorithmically... 

How do you decide how many leading digits to drop?

With addtion it's fairly simple, you just left-shift until highest 1 drops off (ignoring the overflow bit) and increment your exponent with every shift.

With multiplication, I'm just not sure...

Comment: While using a composite array type supporting an index range with positive and negative bounds instead of using a record type with elements for sign, exponent and mantissa the IEEE package float_pkg (sources [float_generic_pkg.vhdl, float_generic_pkg-body.vhdl](https://opensource.ieee.org/jgay/Packages/-/tree/c12aae473a809f092415f9ccc9c20986a29c8eb6/ieee)) will support half precision through the user definable type float and will do the right thing and can be used as a learning aide.  Without a [mcve] a dedicated reader might be inclined to use float_pkg to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't complete as it doesn't address all edge-cases, infinities or rounding modes, it also doesn't support subnormals. However, this seems to work:

1. Check if multiplying by zero, return zero if so.
2. Check if multiplying by NaN, return zero if so.
3. Calculate an interim exponent by adding the two exponents. We need to subtract the bias from this to avoid it being double-added.
4. Prepend the inferred `1`s to the mantissae.
5. Multiply the mantissae
6. Truncate this mantissae to the length of your stored mantissa plus 2. (`x.yyyy...` * `y.zzzz...` always equals `aa.bbbb...` if `yyyy...` and `zzzz...` are the same length)
7. The 2 high bits will always be in `{11, 10, 01}` so we check the high bit and right shift by 1 if it's set. We must also increment the exponent if we do this.
8. We then take the low `n-2` bits as our new mantissa.
9. The resultant sing is gained with `l.sign xor r.sign`.
10. Concatenate the whole lot to get the result.

In VHDL, this looks like:

```vhdl
    function "*" (l,r: float) return float is
    variable l_full_mantissa, r_full_mantissa: unsigned(l.mantissa'length downto 0);
    variable multiplied_mantissae: unsigned((l.mantissa'length + 1) * 2 - 1 downto 0);
    variable new_exponent: unsigned(fp_exponent_len - 1 downto 0);
    variable truncated_mantissa: std_logic_vector(l_full_mantissa'length downto 0);
    begin

        -- Check edge conditions

        if (l = fp_zero or r = fp_zero) then
            return fp_zero;
        end if;

        if (l = nan or r = nan) then
            return nan;
        end if;

        -- Calculate the interim exponent
        new_exponent := (unsigned(l.exponent) + unsigned(r.exponent)) - to_unsigned(fp_exponent_bias, get_width_for_unsigned(fp_exponent_bias)); -- Subtract the bias to prevent double counting

        -- Prepend the leading 1s
        l_full_mantissa := unsigned('1' & l.mantissa);
        r_full_mantissa := unsigned('1' & r.mantissa);

        -- Multiply the mantissae
        multiplied_mantissae := l_full_mantissa * r_full_mantissa;

        -- Truncate resulting mantissa to 24 bits
        truncated_mantissa := std_logic_vector(multiplied_mantissae(multiplied_mantissae'high downto multiplied_mantissae'high - l_full_mantissa'length));

        -- Renormalise the result
        -- Result will always be xx.yyyyyyyy...
        -- xx will always be 11, 10 or 01, so if the high bit is 1 we need to right shift once
        if (truncated_mantissa(truncated_mantissa'high) = '1') then
            truncated_mantissa := truncated_mantissa srl 1;
            new_exponent := new_exponent + 1;
        end if;

        report  to_string((l.sign xor r.sign) & std_logic_vector(new_exponent) & std_logic_vector(truncated_mantissa(truncated_mantissa'high - 2 downto 0)));
        return ((l.sign xor r.sign), std_logic_vector(new_exponent), std_logic_vector(truncated_mantissa(truncated_mantissa'high - 2 downto 0)));
    end function;
```